# Barchart in Flot.js showing null values

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

Im trying to get my bar chart to display the a simple series of data.

Its displaying the data correctly however it is filling up the grid with zero values of data that does exist between the range.

See the image.

```
$.plot($('#somediv'), result, {
    lines: {
        show: false
    },
    bars: {
        barWidth: 12,
        horizontal: false,
        align: "center",
        show: true,
        zero:false,
        fill:true,
        fillColor:'#fefefe',
    },        
    points: {
        show: false,
        symbol: "circle",
        fill: false
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true, 
        backgroundColor: '#fefefe', 
        borderColor: '#eee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        clickable: true
    },
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: false, 
            lineWidth: 1
        },
        shadowSize: 0
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: null,

    },
    yaxis: {
        min: 0
    },
    selection: {
        mode: "y"
    },

});
```

and here is the data

```
[{"label":"Sales","data":[["180","23"],["3","12"],["183","10"],["154","5"],["239","4"]]}]
```

and here is the result in the screenshot.

[image]

The data series on the bottom is the product ID, the y axis is the # of Sales of each product

What I want is that each tick shows 1 bar, but I cant understand the documentation from

https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flot isn't filling the grid with nulls; it is correctly plotting the x-values - 180, 3, 183, etc. that you gave it.  If those values don't actually correspond to positions on an axis, you should simply use 1, 2, 3, ... instead.

Comment: 180 corresponds to the product ID, and 23 corresponds to the # of sales. Its assuming there is a range. So perhaps I change the product ID to the product name, which is what I intended from the start.

Comment: @IEnumerable If you go with the name, make sure to include the Categories plugin; it allows you to use strings on the x-axis, and should look exactly as you want.

Comment: hey thanks, I found that out too by looking at the source of the online example. Essentially the solution to my problem was the missing categories plugin and using a text label.